# C# multiple managed dependencies failing when not run with optimizations

Tags: c#, optimization, msbuild, wix, .net-2.0

I've found this utterly hilarious bug when I've been trying to debug my WiX installer's custom actions.

I didn't write the code, but somehow one of my three managed .dlls decides it is invisible to the main .dll, that's referenced and called by WiX, when I turn optimisations off (to debug) for the main .dll.

As I understand, multiple dependencies in WiX are difficult or impossible without using a tool like ILMerge and I'll probably end up splitting everything down into their own separate .dlls and have loads of custom actions instead.

**The main question here is:** (*out of pure curiosity*) why are my dependencies loading properly when optimisations are enabled and not without them being enabled?

Comment: You should take care to add a little air to your text so it's easier to read (and thus giving your question more views and possibly answers).

Comment: I have no problem having multiple dependencies in my WiX installer.  Its not clear what you mean by "splitting everything down into their own sepeate .dlls" when that should be aleady the case based on the description you gave.

Comment: @Ramhound Don't worry about that, that's just context.